# How do I make a Bootstrap 2.x.x modal dialog draggable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, draggable

How do I make a Bootstrap 2.x.x modal dialog draggable?

I have tried various examples, with zero luck. I assume they are not applicable to Bootstrap, but that may be a bad assumption.

Am I over-complicating this?

With jQuery, I figured I would just do this:

```
$("#idForModal").draggable();
```

But, it does nothing, and there are no console errors in WebKit.

EDIT: Following added.

Perhaps it is because a modal is an iFrame, and can't be dragged? Nope - that's isn't it, because this works. http://jsfiddle.net/nj6ST/show/

Comment: OK. OP here. I've since learned the single line of code above works for other modals I have in the app. Just not the one I decided to experiment with. Ugh. I hate Murphy's Law. So, I am closing this, as the issue is clearly something else wrong with the problematic modal.

Answer (score 0):

This code does work:

```
$("#idForModal").draggable();
```

There is something else wrong with my code preventing it from working.

Comment: draggable() is part of jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "modal", "Modal" creates a "div" behind the content and prevents the user from using other screen controls 
if you want test: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgardleal/Hw2hb/)

```
var oldX = 0;
var oldY = 0;
var mouseDown = false;
$('.modal_').mousedown(function(e){
   log('mousedown');
   oldX = e.clientX;
   oldY = e.clientY;
    console.log(oldX);
    mouseDown = true;
}).mouseup(function(e){
   log('mosueup');
    mouseDown = false;
}).mousemove(function(e){    
    if(mouseDown ){
        self = $(this);      
      var top = parseInt(self.css('top').replace('px', ''));
       var left = parseInt(self.css('left').replace('px', ''));

        log(left + (oldX - e.clientX)  + ' , ' + top);
        self.css('left', (left + e.clientX-oldX) + 'px');
        self.css('top', (top + e.clientY-oldY) + 'px');

        oldX = e.clientX;
        oldY = e.clientY;
    }
});
$('.modal_').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```